# How to insert data in 2D array in C

Tags: arrays, c, matrix

Firstly sorry for my bad english. I have a task of finding the minors of a matrix and writing them to a binary file. I got a problem while writing the code. I tried to insert data using for loop but the result was not what i expected. I %100 sure getCofactor() and determinantOfMatrix() are working correctly because when I run the second code, I don't get any errors and the results are correct. I guess I didn't use the loops correctly and I am newbie in C. Could you help me solve the problem?

```
int **calculateMinor(int **mat, int n) {
    .
    .
    .

    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        for(int m = 0; m < n; m++) {

            for (int p = 0; p < n; p++) {
                for (int q = 0; q < n; q++) {
                        getCofactor(mat, temp, p, q, n);
                        minor = determinantOfMatrix(temp, n - 1);
                        print[k][m] = minor;
                        printf("%d", minor);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return print;
    free(temp);
    free(print);
}
```

And this is my first attempt at finding minors, it's actually working, but when I write this  way I cannot save the data to the binary file.

```
int **calculateMinor(int **mat, int n) {
    .
    .
    .
    for (int p = 0; p < n; p++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < n; q++) {
            getCofactor(mat, temp, p, q, n);
            minor = determinantOfMatrix(temp, n - 1);
            printf("Minor = %d\n", minor);
        }
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

EDIT:
It is function for save to binary file. My problem is not saving data to file. Data is not saved correctly.

```
void savefile(int **mat, int **minor, int n) {

    char filename[64];
    printf("Enter the file name for saving: ");
    scanf("%s", &filename);
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "ab");

    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: The file could not be created!\n");
    } else {
        fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        for(int m = 0; m < n; ++m) {
            fwrite(mat[m], sizeof(mat[m][0]), n, fp);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            fwrite(minor[i], sizeof(minor[i][0]), n, fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Data is stored successfully\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't specified where exactly the problem is.  You say "I cannot save the data to the binary file." Why not?  Please show how you tried to write to the file, and _what_ you want to write.  Thanks.

Comment: `int **mat` is not a 2D array and not allocated contiguously so it is a very bad choice for binary representation of a 2D array. You should rewrite this to work with 2D arrays instead - as a bonus it will also perform faster. It might be wise to encapsulate them in a struct.